# How do I correctly insert page numbering with an offset in OpenOffice?

Tags: formatting, openoffice-writer

I formatted my document's cover sheet with page style `First Page` and the second page with page style `Index`. All following pages have the `Standard` page style and a footer. The footer contains the page number, which I placed there through `Insert` > `Fields` > `Other...` > `Page` > `Page numbers` > `Arabic` with an `Offset` of **-2**.

When I insert an index on page 2 it displays wrong / the initial page numbers without the offset!

How can I correct this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about how to use Open Office.

Comment: Oh ok, **sorry** about that. I thought this would be the correct community to ask at, because it's about writing and Word / Writer formats. Could you please tell me: which stackexchange community is a better place to ask?

Comment: @Dargmuesli No worries, will send it to Superuser for you. General-purpose software is off-topic here unless it's a writing-specific feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

The use of an offset is in this case an **incorrect way** of "correcting" OpenOffice's page numbering system.

## Solution

The correct way to start page numbering with an offset is to `Insert` > `Manual Break...` with `Page break` selected, the style set to `Standard` (or whatever you like) **and `Change page number` selected**! If you want the following page to be page 1 you leave the default value of 1 in the number input box below and hit `OK`.

With the first pages having a format other than `Standard` you can then `Insert` > `Footer` > `Default` and `Insert` > `Fields` > `Page Number`.

If done right, the third page [my case] should be labeled as `1` and the index should display the same, correct page numbers after you right-click it and select `Update Index/Table`!